# Replacing multiple data columns below threshold

Tags: r, types, import

I am trying to import a big environmental dataset of chemical analyses. This dataset is organized as follow:

- First `10 columns` are sample information (e.g. laboratory, monitoring station, date, coordinates, etc.).
- Subsequent `(more than 90 columns)` are observations for different variables (say Aluminium, pH, Copper, etc.)

The big issue is left-censored data are written as say `"< 0.02"` and this value is different for each parameter. When I import the `csv` file all columns in which there is at least one left-censored value is imported as `Factor datatype`.  I would like to replace every left-censored by a basic rule:

```
 - Replace "< X" for value "X/sqrt(2)".
```

This is just an example on how I would like to initially manage this data. Replacing each column is unviable since there are so many parameters and threshold may vary even within same parameter and laboratory (given laboratory equipment renewal).

Thanks you in advance.

Note: I have uploaded an extract of my dataset to be more specific.
It is available here:
http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/722215/sample.csv

Comment: The disadvantage of such a strategy is that the value "< X" will necessarily be a character value. So at the very least, this should be amended to request a new display column or to build an output function that would do such a task. I think building a dataframe with a lower limit of le=inearity value for named variable would make a lot more sense. Then the function could look up a lower limit and output a character value that reflects each variables limits.

Comment: I am new to R. Theoretically, I can think in a function to identify every value beginning with "<" and take the second part of the character value as a number and replace them with "x/sqrt(2)". Yet, I do not know if this is feasible in R.

Also, you should note that even for the same variable, threshold limits will vary due to different labs and equipment performing the analyses. Therefore, I would like to think in a more generic function.

Comment: Your comment is confusing. It shows me that we do not yet know how your data is currently represented. If it is a csv file where the "<" character precedes numbers then none of hte R `read.` functions will considert that column numeric unless you force it to be so ... and then the items with "<" in them will be NA. Show some data in it's raw form.

Comment: I am sorry to be so confusing. I uploaded a sample file in the edit. I have no problem importing them via Rstudio, but the datatype when there is at least one "< X" value is a character.

When I try to force it to be numeric it simply removes all "<" and replace it by the number all alone.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd recommend setting stringsAsFactors = FALSE in read.table or read.csv

Then for each column you want to sub out for example "0.2" and replace it with your equation, and then evaluate that expression, eg: `eval(parse(text = gsub("<(.*)","\\1/sqrt(2)","<0.2")))`

to do this for all you can use dplyr's mutate_at

```
library(dplyr)
tdat <- data.frame(Site = letters[1:4], d1 = c(0,0,"<5",4), d2 = c("<0.5",0,7,4), stringsAsFactors = F)

myfun <- function(x){eval(parse(text = gsub("<(.*)","\\1/sqrt(2)",x)))}

tdat <- tdat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_at(vars(d1:d2), .funs = funs(myfun))
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval(parse` - why not just use a normal function?

Comment: I guess I wanted to evaluate an equation held in a string so eval(parse seemed allowable. You could also use `myfun <- function(x){ifelse(is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))),as.numeric(gsub("<(.*)","\\1",x))/sqrt(2), as.numeric(x))}` but this hardly seems neater to me, although I know using `eval(parse` is generally frowned upon